# Can I become a dependent in Ireland while working in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, ireland, non-citizens

I am presently working in the UK. I want to keep my job and also get a dependent visa because my wife works in Ireland. So my question is can I have this dependent visa while holding the work permit in the UK? I have this confusion that whether my work permit in the UK becomes invalid if I apply for a dependent Visa in Ireland. Both are not citizens in either of the countries and don't belong to EEA.

Comment: Where do you plan to reside?  Are you hoping to live with your wife in Ireland and work remotely from there for your employer in the UK?  Are you planning to stay in the UK but be able to visit your wife in Ireland frequently without having to apply repeatedly for visitor visas?  Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I want to reside in Ireland although I tend to frequently travel to the UK for work. I also like to work remotely as well which depends on the employer I assume.

Comment: Have you asked your employer about keeping your job while living in Ireland?  This sort of arrangement is typically difficult to work out unless you become an independent contractor or, if your employer has an Irish payroll, an employee of a company in Ireland.  With both of those arrangements you would no longer need a UK work permit.